# compute this integral using cauchy's formula

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

$$\oint_{\gamma}\frac{z^2+2z-5}{(4+z^2)^2(z^2+2z+2)}$$
$\gamma = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \:\mid\: |z| = R \},\; R > 0$

I think this integral depends on the values that $R$ takes on.
there are four points where the function is not analytic $-1\pm i$ and $\pm2i$
so when $R < \sqrt2$ f is analytic and since $\gamma$ is a smooth, closed and simple curve by cauchy's theorem it should be equal to $0$
 and when $\sqrt2 < R < 2$ I thought that by applying cauchy's formula to $f(z)=\frac{z^2+2z-5}{(4+z^2)^2}$ and for some point $w$ and after deriving the formula once I would be able to find it but it's been an hour that I'm struggling to solve this so I decided to ask for help
I would appreciate any advices, tips or methods on how to get to the answer.

thanks!

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{C}\setminus |z|=R$ rather than $\mathbb{C} \:/\: |z|=R$?  The first means $\mathbb{C}$ without $|z|=R$ and the second is a quotient.

Comment: $\gamma$ is a circle centered at the origin and a radius of $R$

Comment: @NickPeterson I meant $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\textbf{ such that}\lvert z\rvert=R\}$ so yean I think that's what I actually meant

Comment: I updated your post with slightly different notation for the set definition.  (I usually use `\mid` for a "such that" line.)

Comment: I don't see why cauchy wouldn't work.. computations may be a pain but it should be straightforward. Where do you find difficulties?

Comment: @Ant in manipulating cauchy's formula maybe 
and when $\sqrt2 < R < 2$ there are two singularities and when $R > 2$ there are four and I'm only used to the case when there are only one
I'm still new to complex integration.

Comment: @1.2.3 You may want to specify that in the question, so one knows where to help. In any case two or more singularities doesn't change a lot, you just need to compute the residue at each pole and sum them up. For the case where $R > 2$ you can calculate the 4 residues and add them up, or use the residue at infinity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_at_infinity), which in your case it should be 0 if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given integral is $$\int_\gamma\dfrac{z^2+2z-5}{(z+2i)^2(z-2i)^2(z+i+1)(z-i+1)}dz$$

So the singularities occur at $z=2i,-2i,-i-1,-1+i$ each of which are poles and $\gamma=\{z:|z|=R\}$. If we choose $R>2$, then all the singularities will fall inside the circle. In that case the value of the integral will be $2\pi i\sum\text{Res}_{z=z_i}f(z)$. If we choose $1<R<2$ then the value of integrals with singularities $2i$ and $-2i$ will be 0.

Comment: thank you for your answer I get the first part but if you don't mind can you please elucidate why when  $1<R<2$ (perhaps you meant $\sqrt2<R<2$) the integral is 0 ?

Comment: can you just plot the points on the plane ? The last two singularities are at $(-1,-1),(-1,1)$. So any circle of radius $>1$ and $<2$ will make the singularities at $(0,2)$ and $(0,-2)$ fall outside the circle